# Is it possible to get a list of all the jumbled English words?

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary

I have made a scramble-like game (using Swing) of forming words from random letters on a grid. The program works perfectly. However, I wish to implement one more action: when no more words can be formed, the game should end. Now I'm not sure if this is realistic, but I am looking for a list of all the possible jumbled English words. Is there anywhere I can get this so that I can compare with the remaining letters?

Also, the dictionary I am using is incomplete because it omits the small 2-letter and some 3-letter words. Is there a better list of English words out there?

Comment: So you want to compare your words with several million Strings in an `ArrayList`? Sounds like a great performance :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [SOWPODS word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOWPODS). It has all the two-letter and three-letter words used in Scrabble. At the bottom of the Wikipedia article, you'll find a link to a page where you can download the list.

To use the word list efficiently, store it in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

With the help of the trie, you can explore the grid using [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find all the dictionary words hidden in the grid. Finally, compare these words to the ones found by the player.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Well, would you mind letting me know why my question got 5 downvotes (so far)? Isn't this a legit question?

Comment: There is a legitimate algorithmic question here. If you had included a minimal piece of executable code and asked something specific about it, your question would have been received better by the other users. I answered anyway because it's a topic I know and like, and I reckoned I had useful advice for you. If I did help you, please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @John There is a guideline for people reviewing questions that says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". I guess asking for a word list could be judged as asking for an off-site resource.